# VHDL testbench variable clock/wave generation

Tags: vhdl, testing

A testbench for one sub-entity in my system currently defines a helper process to generate a clock-like waveform at the command of the main stimulus process.  A simplified version of it is:

```
shared variable gen_period : time := 10 us;
signal gen_all : boolean := false;  -- wavegen enabled
signal gen_A : boolean := false;    -- run this signal
signal A_in : std_logic;            -- manual input (wavegen disabled)
signal A_gen : std_logic;           -- generated output (internal)
signal A_out : std_logic;           -- final output
...
A_generate: process
    if gen_A then
        A_gen <= '1';
        wait for gen_period/2;
        A_gen <= '0';
        wait for gen_period/2;
    else
        A_gen <= '0';
        wait for 1 ns;
    end if;
end process;

A_out <= A_gen when gen_all else A_in;
```

The full system has a few more signals, but this is the basic idea.  `gen_all` applies to all signals and allows a manual signal pattern to be applied when disabled, while `gen_A` is basically a clock enable for that specific signal.  The other important feature is that the period of the clock is variable.

Putting this all together it means that the main testbench stimulus process can either manually generate edges or can just request a pulse train at a specific interval and then wait for a longer time (typically `gen_period * N`) to generate multiple pulses.  It works quite well.

---

Now though I'm interested in generalising this a bit, in particular to instantiate several such independent generators in the testbench for a higher-level design that contains multiple of the original component.  However I'm having trouble finding the right way to do so.

My first attempt was to wrap the code above into its own entity, declaring all but `A_gen` as ports of the entity.  Doing this required changing `gen_period` from a variable to a signal, since AFAIK ports must be signals.

Unfortunately, back in the original testbench stimulus process, whenever it tried to assign a new period it had to do this as a signal assignment, which didn't take effect until later.  Additionally the `wait for gen_period * 5` calls appeared to be using the original value for gen_period rather than one just assigned.  (This is not surprising behaviour for signals, but in this case it's undesired.)

Is there a better way to encapsulate this functionality, and retain instant behaviour of the variable?  The code is only going to be used in a testbench, so it does not need to be synthesisable.  I'm using Xilinx ISim.

(I realise that I can do a `for .. generate` to instantiate multiple instances in the higher level testbench, but this doesn't allow me to share the code between separate testbenches, which is also desirable to avoid duplication.)

I can live with having only one instance of the `gen_period` variable shared between all generators in the high level testbench, but I would prefer to have one per generator instance.

---

Since the answers seem to be focusing on "clock" rather than "waveform", it seems that I need to clarify the usage a bit more.  This is inside a testbench:

```
stim_proc : process
begin
    -- (reset and other setup instructions here)

    -- generate "slow" pulse train
    gen_all <= true;
    gen_period := 250 ns;
    gen_A <= true;
    wait for gen_period * 20;
    gen_A <= false;
    wait for gen_period;
    -- (perform tests on logic for slow pulses here)

    -- generate "fast" pulse train
    gen_period := 10 ns;
    gen_A <= true;
    wait for gen_period * 50;
    gen_A <= false;
    wait for gen_period;
    -- (perform tests on logic for fast pulses here)

    -- generate asymmetric pulses
    gen_all <= false;
    A_in <= '1';
    wait for 100 ns;
    A_in <= '0';
    wait for 200 ns;
    A_in <= '1';
    wait for 150 ns;
    A_in <= '0';
    wait for 50 ns;
    -- (perform tests on logic for asymmetric pulses here)

    -- etc
end process;
```

These are the simple ones; there are a few more complex ones involving multiple signals happening simultaneously, but that's not really important for this question.  The important point is that this is all sequential code and both the pulse generation and the waiting need to act on the most recently set period, not any delayed value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a procedure with an out parameter. The procedure can be declared in a package and called with different parameters for different 'clock' signals.

Here is an example of a [clock_gen procedure](https://github.com/kevinpt/vhdl-extras/blob/master/rtl/extras/timing_ops.vhdl#L463-L478) from [VHDL-extras](https://github.com/kevinpt/vhdl-extras):

```
subtype duty_cycle is real range 0.0 to 1.0;

procedure clock_gen( signal Clock : out std_ulogic; signal Stop_clock : in boolean;
  constant Clock_period : in delay_length; constant Duty : duty_cycle := 0.5 ) is
  constant HIGH_TIME : delay_length := Clock_period * Duty;
  constant LOW_TIME  : delay_length := Clock_period - HIGH_TIME;
begin
  Clock <= '0';

  while not Stop_clock loop
    wait for LOW_TIME;
    Clock <= '1';
    wait for HIGH_TIME;
    Clock <= '0';
  end loop;
end procedure;
```

The constant input period can be exchanged with a variable for simulation environments.

Usage example:

```
architecture rtl of my_entity is
  signal SimStop      : boolean     := false;
  signal my_clock1    : std_ulogic;
  signal my_clock2    : std_ulogic;
begin

  clock_gen(my_clock1, SimStop, 10.000 ns);
  clock_gen(my_clock2, SimStop,  6.666 ns);

  -- ...

  process
  begin
    --
    -- some stimuli
    --

    wait for 10 ns;
    SimStop := true;
    wait;
  end process;
end architecture;
```

**Example to generate a waveform with an generic waveform:**

```
type T_TIME_VECTOR is array(NATURAL range <>) of TIME;

constant myWaveform : T_TIME_VECTOR  := (
  -- generate "slow" pulse train
  20 * 250 ns,
  250 ns,
  -- generate "fast" pulse train
  50 * 10 ns,
  10 ns
);

procedure generateWaveform(signal Wave : out BOOLEAN; Waveform: T_TIME_VECTOR; InitialValue : BOOLEAN) is
  variable State : BOOLEAN := InitialValue;
begin
  Wave <= State;
  for i in Waveform'range loop
    wait for Waveform(i);
    State := not State;
    Wave  <= State;
  end loop;
end procedure;

signal mySignal : BOOLEAN;

-- begin of architecture
generateWaveform(mySignal, myWaveform);
```

Comment: This looks more promising but it still seems too concurrent for the required usage.  It's fine for a clock, but I need a controlled waveform.

Comment: @Miral You can produce any signal with this method, it's just a question on how complex your procedure is. A procedure is as powerful as a process - both are sequential. You process example is again evaluated from the beginning, if one run is complete. You can imitate this in a procedure, while framing your code with a endless-loop. See my example: `while not Stop_clock loop ... end loop;`.

Comment: But I don't see how this improves anything.  I would still have to have uniquely-named signals for each separate waveform, and the interval can't be a parameter because it has to be changed inside the stimulus process.  See the updated question.

Comment: @Miral As I said, it's just a question of the procedure's complexity. I added an example, that generates a waveform for type boolean. As an input it takes a VCD-like list of delays between toggle events. This example can be extended to every type. You could hand-over a second list of std_logic_vectors, which are assigned to the wave signal at every listed event.

Comment: Ok, I admit that's possible, but it still seems like a considerable departure from the current code, and brittle to changes in the test ordering.  I was hoping to keep the tests immediately adjacent to the generation, as in the question.  (Also BTW note that your code doesn't do the same thing as mine -- during that 20 * 250 ns period mine is generating multiple pulses.)

Comment: @Miral Is your code complete? `wait for 250 ns * 20;` is a single wait statement, nothing is happening in between. Here is a complete example of my [PoC.io.uart.rx](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/tb/io/uart/uart_rx_tb.vhdl#L64-L90) testbench. It uses the presented technique to generate a Clock signal of 100 MHz, a Reset pulse with a pause of 50 ns, and a complex waveform `UART_RX` for a 5 byte UART transmission.

Comment: Yes, the code is complete, if you look at both code blocks.  When `gen_A` is true, it generates a sequence of pulses on `A_out`.  While the stimulus process is paused for multiple clocks, the generator process itself is still running and generating multiple edges.  The key point though is that it's the stimulus process that's telling the generator process what to generate and when, while in your version the two run mostly independently.  I *have* done the independent generator thing in some other contexts (eg. an SPI slave emulator) but I was hoping for something more controlled in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the clock generator as an entity also. Instead of trying to assign `gen_period` as a signal, try defining it as a [generic](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.in/2010/03/generics-in-vhdl-construction-of.html) in the entity definition as shown below:

```
entity clock_gen is
   generic (
       gen_period : time := 10 us  
   );
   port (  
       signal gen_all : boolean := false;  -- wavegen enabled
       signal gen_A : boolean := false;    -- run this signal
       signal A_in : std_logic;            -- manual input (wavegen disabled)
       signal A_gen : std_logic;           -- generated output (internal)
       signal A_out : std_logic            -- final output  
   );  
end entity clock_gen;
```

Now, when you try to instantiate the entity in your higher-level module, it will allow you to define the `gen_period` parameter separately for each instance of `clock_gen`. The default value of the parameter will be considered as 10 us if it is not mentioned separately during instantiation. Two examples of usage in architecture are shown below:

```
gen1: clock_gen  
   generic map (gen_period => 100 us)  
   port map (  
     gen_all => <some_port1>;
     gen_A   => <some_port2>;
     A_in    => <some_port3>;
     A_gen   => <some_port4>;
     A_out   => <some_port5> 
  );
gen2: clock_gen  
   generic map (gen_period => 1 us)  
   port map (  
     gen_all => <some_port1>;
     gen_A   => <some_port2>;
     A_in    => <some_port3>;
     A_gen   => <some_port4>;
     A_out   => <some_port5> 
  );`
```

If you have multiple instances of `clock_gen` with the same `gen_period`, you can even call the instantiation inside a `for ... generate` procedure in your code.

Comment: Generics are not variable at runtime so this does not answer the question.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sure, however, simply making gen_period a port solves the problem.  In addition, an entity allows more efficient forms of clk to be used than a procedure.  IE:  Clk <= not Clk after tperiod_Clk/2 ;

Comment: As specified, generics are not sufficient because they're not variable, and making it a port didn't work because it introduces delayed-write semantics that are undesirable.  And the `Clk <= not Clk after` trick is only suitable for infinite run clocks, which this is definitely not.